# Error while running Spark application in Intellij - NoClassDefFoundError com/google/common/util/concurrent/internal/InternalFutureFailureAccess

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea, sbt, guava

I have an Apache Spark 2.0 application written in Scala (2.11.12), built using SBT tool 1.2.8. When I'm trying to run the app in Intellij (2020.3.2 Ultimate), I get the following error -

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/util/concurrent/internal/InternalFutureFailureAccess
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:756)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:468)
    .....
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.util.concurrent.internal.InternalFutureFailureAccess
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
```

On googling/searching Stackoverflow, it seems this is caused by some weird Guava dependency issues. I have these added to my Dependencies.scala

```
dependencies += "com.google.guava" % "guava" % "30.1-jre"
dependencies += "com.google.guava" % "failureaccess" % "1.0"
```

That didn't solve the issue. Also tried adding `"com.google.guava" % "listenablefuture" % "1.0"` to the dependencies, but that didn't help either. Tried doing File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart in Intellij but I still get the issue.

Could someone please help?

Comment: did you try sbt clean?

Comment: @msbomrel Yup, did try using `sbt clean`, deleting the target folders and running the build again. Still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, adding `com.google.guava:failureaccess` to external libraries to my project `(File -> Project Structure -> Libraries)` helped.